# C# || How can I pass string-info from method to other

Tags: c#

Heyy, I would like to pass info from a string from one method to another method

I am a beginner to C#, so don't make it overcomplicated :))

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        //the information from Input needs to go to 'Follow'
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void Follow()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        //the information from Input has to be printed here
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You would pass them via function parameter arguments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters  (Or via global state mutation, I don't recommend that though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        Follow(input);
        //the information from Input needs to go to 'Follow'
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Follow(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

`Follow()` method need a parameter to receive the string and print it -> `Follow(string)`.

`Follow(string)` method is an instance method/function, it need to be `static` for calling it in your static `Main()` method.

**Output**

[image: output]

**References**

[static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)
[Passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Same as you did in the `Console.Writeline(input)`.

First you have to receive the paramenter you want to pass in the receving method, like the next

```
private void follow(string input)
{
   //The code you already have
}
```

and then you have to pass it in your main method

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    follow(input); // This line here
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you just need to pass the variable as a parameter to the Follow() method.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    Follow(input);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void Follow(string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    //the information from Input has to be printed here
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```